# Eigenvalue question.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

For my question I need to prove that if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of the invertible operator $T\in\mathcal{L}(V)$ then $\lambda^{-1}$ is an eigenvalue of $T^{-1}$.

I have tried for a while to get it to work but to no avail. If anyone could provide a hint on how to start then that would be amazing, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Let $\lambda$ be an eigenvalue of $T$ with eigenvector $\vec v$. Then:

$$\begin{array}{rcll}
T\vec v &=& \lambda \vec v \\
\vec v &=& \lambda T^{-1}\vec v & \text{multiply both sides by }T^{-1}\text{ on the left} \\
\lambda^{-1} \vec v &=& T^{-1}\vec v & \text{multiply both sides by }\lambda^{-1} \\
T^{-1}\vec v &=& \lambda^{-1} \vec v & \text{equality is symmetric} \\
\end{array}$$

Therefore $\lambda^{-1}$ is an eigenvalue of $T^{-1}$.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks so much!